# Probability Generating function

Tags: probability

in a test 30% of questions are worth 1 mark and 70% worth 4 marks.

If someone answers 8 questions show that she cannot score exactly 15 marks.

I have the probability generating function (0.3t+0.7t^4)^8 but do I need to find (or show I cannot find) 1/15!(Gdif 15 with input 0)?

Does this work? If x= # 1mark questions answered and y= #4 mark questions answered then x+4y=15 and x+y=8. Solving gives y=2 1/3 which she could not have answered.

Is there a way of using probability generating functions to answer this?  (that is what the chapter topic is about?) It seems too trivial otherwise.

Comment: Note that (0.3t+0.7t^4)^8=t^8(0.3+0.7t^3)^8 hence the only monomials present in the PGF have degree 8+3k for k between 0 and 8. Conclude by showing that 15 is not one of these (the closest possible degrees are 14 and 17).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of probabilities, it is just that you cannot sum to exactly $15$ with $8$ answers worth either $1$ or $4$ marks.